# Sample Size Formula for Wilson Score, Clopper Pearson, and Jeffrey's

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistical-power, excel, jeffreys-prior

I am interested in finding the sample size formulas for proportions using the Wilson Score, Clopper Pearson, and Jeffrey's methods to compare with the Wald method. Also if anyone has code to replicate these methods in R or Excel would help to be able to repeat the task for different tests.

I understand how these methods work conceptually but was hoping to find a better method to calculate them because the project I am working on will need to eventually be run by someone without the same conceptual understanding. Some of these methods, i.e. Jeffrey's and Wilson, are computationally very difficult in determining sample size alone and this is where I am requesting help.

Comment: Questions asking solely for code are 
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: In R see the binom package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/binom/index.html